# GAE Session does not behave the same offline or online

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, servlets

I have this code :

```
private String delete(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Seller seller) throws Exception {

    //check data
    if(req.getParameter("equipmentId") == null) {

    throw new Exception("equipmentId undefined");

}

//build
Equipment equipment = new Equipment(Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("equipmentId")));

//delete
dbEquipment.delete(equipment);

//remove in array list
for(int i = 0; i < seller.getListEquipment().size(); i++) {

    if(seller.getListEquipment().get(i).getId() == equipment.getId()) {

        seller.getListEquipment().remove(i);

    }

}

//response
return "ok";
```

}

The seller attribute passed is from the HTTPSession : **((Seller) req.getSession().getAttribute("user"))**

This code update my object Seller fine offline but online the update doesn't show up, it's still the old object/ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving object back into session after you update it's contents.

Comment: ok i'm gonna try this, but i don't see why i have to do it actually. Thanks ;)

Comment: nice this is working -> but definitely a *bug* in Google App Engine/Java/Session. Something wrong with carrying the session over the HRD system may be...

Comment: Why do you believe it's a bug? How should a session know that you changed objects contents?

Comment: Because the session object is passed as a reference to the actual method, so changing the content of this object is changing the session object.
And i can confirm you that this is working offline without this fix but not online so there is something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

In your appengine-web.xml add this line :

```
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
```

I am not sure, but this has been a repeated mistake for me. :P

In addition, you need to make sure that all your objects that are you going to persist to the session implement the java.io.Serializable interface.  The reason the object needs to be serializable is because App Engine stores session data in the datastore and memcache.  Any objects referenced by the value you put in the session must be serializable, so the entire object graph is available.  What I found interesting is that it must commit the session data in an transactionally based manner because I had also stored a String in the session and that wasn’t persisted either.  If the object isn’t serializable, the app will NOT fail in a local development machine, but will fail when deployed to the cloud.

Source: http://afewguyscoding.com/2011/02/httpsession-google-app-engine/

Comment: no it was enabled before, but thanks for the try and yes everything is serializable (in the session object)